# Build slick with new changes using Makefile

Tags: javascript, jquery, makefile, slick.js

---

I have made few customization's on latest npm published [slick carousel](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/releases/tag/v1.8.1). but i can't find a way to minified my script and style files. seems there is a `Makefile` that was performing particular task i think. i have tried `make build` command on terminal and getting error. please refer the below message.

**Error:** Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Please find my **Makefile** from below,

```
build: components slick.js slick.css
  @component build --dev

components: component.json
  @component install --dev

.PHONY: clean
```

and respective **component.json**

```
{
    "name": "slick",
    "repo": "kenwheeler/slick",
    "description": "the last carousel you'll ever need",
    "version": "1.8.2",
    "keywords": ["ui", "jquery", "carousel", "responsive", "slider"],
    "dependencies": {
        "component/jquery": "*"
    },
    "development": {},
    "scripts": {
        "slick/slick.js": "slick.js"
    },
    "styles": {
        "slick/slick.css": "slick.css",
        "slick/slick-theme.css": "slick-theme.css"
    }
}
```

Looking forward a reply.

---

Thank You.

Comment: "it didn't work for me" is never a useful description of a problem.  However, I can immediately see one issue with your makefile: you should not have backslashes at the end of the list of prerequisites.  Maybe that will fix your "it didn't work" but since you don't tell us anything about what "didn't work" means, we can't say for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and guides @MadScientist. please refer the updated question.

Comment: If you Google or use the SO search box to search for _make missing separator_ you'll find a bajillion and a half explanations for this error.  There are so many I can't even decide which one(s) to mark your question as a duplicate of.